# Unable to make admin interface connection to server when moving a mailbox

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange-2003, migration, amazon-ebs

I have an existing Exchange 2003 server running on Windows Server 2003. I am in the process of replacing our current server infrastructure and virtualizing it all in Hyper-V.

I have Essential Business Server 2008 installed in 3 separate VMs and running. Everything seems to be working fine so far.

I am now trying to migrate my exchange mailboxes over to the new exchange server in the messaging server and every time I try I get this error:
MapiExceptionNetworkError: Unable to make admin interface connection to server. (hr=0x80040115, ec=-2147221227)

I have done some searching and found solutions like adding the computer to the exchange domain servers groups and install group, also making sure the user logged into the new server is in the proper groups. I also saw a solution in making sure that any unused NICs are disabled. I've tried all that to no avail.

Comment: I assume that the old exchange server and the Essentials server are in different AD Forests? (as the essentials server must be the root of the forest)

Comment: Actually it isn't. The setup wizard connected it to the existing forest to migrate everything to the new servers. I will then decommission the old servers once everything is migrated.

Comment: Ah ok, fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The information store was not started on the new Exchange server. Seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

The information store was not started on the old Exchange server for me.